# Loop over results from Path.glob() (Pathlib)

Tags: python, glob, pathlib

I'm struggling with the result of the Path.glob() method of the Pathlib module in Python 3.6.

```
from pathlib import Path

dir = Path.cwd()

files = dir.glob('*.txt')
print(list(files))
>> [WindowsPath('C:/whatever/file1.txt'), WindowsPath('C:/whatever/file2.txt')]

for file in files:
    print(file)
    print('Check.')
>>
```

Evidently, *glob* found files, but the for-loop is not executed. How can I loop over the results of a pathlib-glob-search?

Comment: The iterator got consumed at `list(files)`, you'll have to do `files = dir.glob('*.txt')` again

Answer (score 65, accepted):

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> 
>>> _dir = Path.cwd()
>>> 
>>> files = _dir.glob('*.txt')
>>> 
>>> type(files)
<class 'generator'>
```

Here, `files` is a `generator`, which can be read only once and then get exhausted. So, when you will try to read it second time, you won't have it.

```
>>> for i in files:
...     print(i)
... 
/home/ahsanul/test/hello1.txt
/home/ahsanul/test/hello2.txt
/home/ahsanul/test/hello3.txt
/home/ahsanul/test/b.txt
>>> # let's loop though for the 2nd time
... 
>>> for i in files:
...     print(i)
... 
>>>
```

Comment: I got it, thanks. I was unaware that generators get "exhausted" or "consumed". I'll dig deeper into it to understand more. However, my code works now. Thanks for your help (also thanks to Moses)!

Comment: Just FYI, `dir` is a builtin function, so is best avoided as a variable name